# Issue with AWS IAM role and policy attachment for s3 access with terraform

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, terraform, amazon-iam

i have few s3 buckets being used in dev, test and prod environment and i am planning to create a role ( which will allow me to access those s3 buckets and attach the policy ( i.e to list and do some other permission on that buckets present in different envs say dev,test,prod)
i have written this for that -

```
####################################
## Role Per Service - GO-Service  ##
####################################

resource "aws_iam_policy" "go-service" {
  
  name = "go-service-policy"

  policy = <<EOF
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Action": [
        "s3:ListBucket"
      ],
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::orbital-go-download-*"
    }
  ]
}
EOF
}

resource "aws_iam_role" "go-service" {
  name = "go-service-role"

  assume_role_policy = <<EOF
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "",
            "Action": "sts:AssumeRole",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::orbital-go-download-*"
            ],
            "Principal": {
                "Service": "s3.amazonaws.com"
            }
        }
    ]
}
EOF
}

resource "aws_iam_role_policy_attachment" "go-services-attach" {
  role     = aws_iam_role.go-service.name
  policy_arn = aws_iam_policy.go-service.arn 
}
```

but with this the prob is i might be getting 3 roles getting created ( since we are creating is for 3 k8s clusters say dev,test and prod ) and i need to have one common role which can access all the s3 buckets needed to access the biz service i.e. biz-go-download-{dev,test,prod} bucket.
any help there how would i achieve this requirement , i am new to terraform ? Any suggestion help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: You could use Terraform workspaces: https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/state/workspaces.html. Then, what you could do is add the workspace name in the role/policy name and they will be different for each environment. Example: `name = "go-service-role-${terraform.workspace}".

Comment: why do you use Terraform? Can't you just use plain Cloud Formation?

Comment: Unrelated but you have your policy as the assume role policy as well. This is wrong and instead the assume role needs to let your service assume it instead. With Kubernertes I'd assume that's using [IRSA](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/iam-roles-for-service-accounts.html) in which case you need to allow the service account via the federated OIDC provider assume the role.

Comment: As to the actual question. It looks like your role currently already creates a single common role that can list all buckets that start with `orbital-go-download-`. Can you clarify what your exact problem is with the role? Do you mean that you want the opposite and instead of the common role you want a role that can only access one of the dev/test/production buckets and then have your dev/test/production services assume the correct one? And if so it's probably worth showing how you currently structure your Terraform code.

Comment: @Perimosh  we generally go with terraform to setup out whole structure. i m bound to it.

Comment: @ydaetskcoR yes that is what i wanted. So we having different services and we are creating a role/policy(to list certain AWS resources as per the service needs) and also we want it for different environments too. so in short - "Be able to specify different IAM user/role/policy for different microservice in different environment". and i am going through this approach but this seems little clumsy ( as with this lets say my dev pod can be able to access the prod or test buckets too which is what i don't want )